# How can I pass the ApplicationViewController to a different class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a single view application that has a subview. That subview contains a form that includes e-mail textfield and password textfield. I need to set the delegates to those textfields to the "global" `this`.

Everything is written code, nothing on the storyboard.

How can I pass my ApplicationViewController to the textfields?

Comment: Is the subView a subclass or is it contained in the viewController you are currently in? If it's in the same viewController just set it to self.

Comment: it's not the same viewController.. self refers to an UIView

Comment: Are you trying to access a viewController from your UIView subclass?

Comment: yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I updated my answer to pass the viewController to the UIView class you are using. UIView needs to change to your subclasses name but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a @property for your viewController and pass that to your UIView class.

In your UIViewClass.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *yourViewController;
```

Then pass the current viewController to your UIView when you create it.

```
UIView *yourView = [UIView new];
yourView.yourViewController = self;
```

Then you can access your viewController directly from in your UIView class.

```
yourTextField.delegate = _yourViewController;
```

Comment: self refers to an UIView, not a viewController.

Comment: Sorry, I updated that, just refresh. The idea is to create a property on your UIView class to hold the reference to your viewController. Then when you create that UIView you can set the property to your viewController and access it directly from within your UIView class.